# Decoding certain customized annotations in political signage, do these symbols have any emerging specific connotations?

Tags: united-states, symbols, conspiracy-theories, qanon

ABC News' [GOP warns HR 1 could be 'absolutely devastating for Republicans'](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/gop-warns-hr-absolutely-devastating-republicans/story?id=76555647) discusses several measures by different parties and at different levels to make voting easier or harder for some.

The caption on the file photo selected for the article reads:

> Supporters of President Donald Trump participate on a 'Stop the Steal' protest at the Georgia State Capitol, after the 2020 presidential election was called for Democratic candidate Joe Biden, in Atlanta, Nov. 7, 2020.

I noticed that two signs have replaced the capital letter "E" with three horizontal *red* lines, looking a bit like the number 3 written in Chinese "三". It occurs twice in "BEIJING BIDEN FOR TREASON" and once in "RIGGED".

I also noticed the added red exclamation sign in the "FACEBOOK TWITTER TRA!SH" sign and the red "S" in "CNN LIES!!!"

Do all these annotations/modifications to the signs represent any specific, emerging connotation? Is this a new code of some kind, perhaps similar to the use of "Q" hints?

---

Cropped, enlarged and sharpened bits from the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLoO.jpg)

[image: Supporters of President Donald Trump participate on a 'Stop the Steal' protest at the Georgia State Capitol, after the 2020 presidential election was called for Democratic candidate Joe Biden, in Atlanta, Nov. 7, 2020.]
[image: Supporters of President Donald Trump participate on a 'Stop the Steal' protest at the Georgia State Capitol, after the 2020 presidential election was called for Democratic candidate Joe Biden, in Atlanta, Nov. 7, 2020.]

[image: Supporters of President Donald Trump participate on a 'Stop the Steal' protest at the Georgia State Capitol, after the 2020 presidential election was called for Democratic candidate Joe Biden, in Atlanta, Nov. 7, 2020.]

This last one may simply be accidental, or an homage to [Sean Spicer's upside-down American flag pin](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2017/03/10/sean-spicer-wore-an-upside-down-flag-pin-the-internet-lost-its-mind/).

Comment: In the last’s picture, I’m pretty sure they’re just holding the sign upside down. Note that the text is upside down too - clearly it’s intended to just be a normal Republican elephant and a voting checkbox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"E" styled as three red stripes clearly is a reference to the Biden campaign logo:

[image: Joe Biden campaign logo]
<sub>Photo by Scott Eisen/Getty Images</sub>

---

"CNN LIES" seems to be quite an old anti-CNN propagandist motto, [traced back](https://olaasm.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/m1gs-media-alert-cnn-lies-to-the-people/) to 2012. It is styled similarly to the "CNN Live" program.

[image: Anti-CNN propaganda]